# Algorithm Problem: Minimum Shard Movement

Tags: algorithm, sharding

I have a shard movement problem in distributed systems.

**【The Problem】**
Initially each partition is responsible for an arbitrary number of shards. (the number can be arbitrary because the system supports moving shard from one partition to another)

Then a new partition comes, and the system needs to reshard. The goal is to make the shard assignment as uniform as possible, i.e. the maximum shard number difference between any two partitions is at most 1, and to minimize the number of moving shards.

For example, let's say initially there were three partitions, P1, P2, and P3. P1 handled 5 shards, P2 handled 3 shards, and P3 handled 1 shard. Then a new partition P4 comes in so the system reshards. The resharding result will be that one partition handles 3 shards, and three partitions each handle 2 shards. Now the problem becomes which partition should handle 3 shards. And for this specific case, it is P1 that should handle 3 shards because otherwise shard movement is not minimal.

**【My Rough Solution】**
Now I have a rough idea that if partition `Pi` has the i-th most shards, then the new number of shards of `Pi` should also be the i-th largest number in the new shard numbers. For example, if the original shard numbers are 10, 2, 1 in partition P1, P2, P3, respectively, then partition P1 should now handle 4 shards, and partition P2, P3, P4(the new partition) each handles 3 shards.

**【My Question】**
I tried some examples and this algorithm works. But I'm not sure if it's correct or not. Is it correct? How to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: don't know which algorithm you have used but this is a typical application of partitioning problem which has an efficient dynamic programming solution

Comment: @mangusta Thanks for the reply! Could you point me to a solution or share the name of the problem? I think this should be a typical problem, but don't know its name so not able to search solutions.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand from your question, what you need is [Consistent Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing). You can find multiple articles about it. Whenever new shard is added, it takes a fair share of objects from other nodes.

Comment: his question is not about redistribution of the keys from old shards to new ones, he wants to redistribute the shards themselves